# Negotiating a raise in a yearly review

Tags: salary, negotiation, raise

Every year, my company does a performance check and salary review. The last time, they just offered an amount (that was fair, a bit below my preference) which I accepted. The next review is coming up. I'm wondering how best to approach this.

Should I negotiate before they give me a figure? ie. Set my expected raise? Or should I wait until the review, get the figure, then negotiate (or not) depending on the amount? Is it rude to turn back a raise and say I deserve more?

I've been keeping track of my accomplishments this year and I think I have a good case for a solid raise. 
- I've gotten a promotion, along with added responsibility. I was just given a token raise for this.
- I've spearheaded and implemented a change which has saved us, conservatively, about 100k a year. This only took me 2 weeks to do.
- I'm now one of the primary contributors to our main money making product.
And a few others
- My manager and others in the business have stated that I've been doing a very good job.

I suspect there will be cultural factors that will affect how I should approach this. For reference, I'm in Australia.

Answer (score 5):

The decision to award salary increase is generally negotiated much before it is announced to employees. I would advise to have a conversation with your manager regarding your expectations much before your yearly performance review.

Comment: You do not know his workplace. Maybe everyone in his workplace gets a raise. He asks how he can get a bigger raise. This is not an answer.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Qualifies more as a comment to me. (Your comment for example tells somewhat the same)

Comment: The question is : "Should I negotiate before they give me a figure?". My answer is: Yes. Then I proceed to explain why, based on my management experience.

Comment: +1 Managers often have to go through a lengthy approval procedure to set raises for their team. Doing that a second time to get a higher raise after it's been approved will be even more difficult.

Comment: @Ajax1995 The yearly review process is pretty standard.  Managers have a pool of money to keep the team as close to cost of living increases as possible.  They divide out that money as best they can, slightly rewarding the better workers, and slightly denying the lesser workers.  Any request for money during that process is going to create a major upset, as it is only likely to be available by taking money from another worker.  It would be best to ask for such a raise early, to ensure more money is allocated into the process, if such a thing is possible.